# springs scheduing jobs for a given

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Spring MVC:
how to schedule jobs at a specific time in a day. schedule time differs every day. time when these jobs needs to be run are available in a database table. I was able to read the data from table but not sure how to schedule them in spring mvc. can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring scheduler requires that you know the time of day at compile time so this is going to get a little weird. But if you want to be creative you can schedule a job at midnight to query the database for the exact time the task should run, sleep until that time, and then execute the task. Something like this:

```
public abstract class DailyTaskRunner {

  // Execute the specific task here
  protected abstract void executeTask();

  // Query the database here
  // Return the number of milliseconds from midnight til the task should start
  protected abstract long getMillisTilTaskStart();

  // Run at midnight every day
  @Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * *")
  public void scheduledTask() {

    long sleepMillis = getMillisTilTaskStart();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      // Handle error
    }

    executeTask();
  }
}
```

You can extend this class once for every job.